# Open Event logs using win32evtlog

Tags: python, windows, winapi, event-log, pywin32

I want to open a specific log to the Windows Event Log, named "Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager". I used this code:

```
    import win32evtlog   

    logtype = 'Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager'
    hand = win32evtlog.OpenEventLog("",logtype)
    flags = win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ|win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_FORWARDS_READ
    while True:
        events = win32evtlog.ReadEventLog(hand, flags,0)
        if events:
            for event in events:
                print ('Event ID:', event.EventID & 0x1FFFFFFF)
```

But it doesn't work, this code open "System" log, instead "Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager".

And I really dont know why.
In the documentation to "win32evtlog.OpenEventLog":

> Points to a null-terminated string that specifies the name of the
>   source that the returned handle will reference. The source name must
>   be a subkey of a logfile entry under the EventLog key in the registry.
>   For example, the source name WinApp would be valid if the registry had
>   the following form:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
>
> System
>
> ```
> CurrentControlSet 
>
>   Services 
>
>     EventLog 
>
>       Application 
>
>         WinApp 
>
>       Security 
>
>       System
> ```
>
> If the source name cannot be found, the event logging service uses the
>   Application logfile with no message files for the event identifier or
>   category.
>
> http://www.sxlist.com/techref/os/win/api/win32/func/src/f65_20.htm

Yes, I have subkey in registry, named "Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager", but in the "System" key.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\System\Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager

Why it doesn't work?
And if it is not a bug, but a feature, what is the way to read this log?

Thanks to your answer

Comment: You should pass NULL, not "" for first argument. Anyway, I think you must use EvtQuery. See here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4265227/1374704 What is the Windows version?

Comment: The Windows version is 2008 and 2003